# What are lexemes and morphemes?

Tags: american-english, british-english, morphemes

I am preparing for my TOEFL test and want to increase my vocabulary. Can anybody please tell me what lexemes and morphemes are, and why they are important?

I have Googled the terms but I need the explanation to be given in a simpler way.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: If you need to know the meaning of a word, the place to look is a dictionary. Just saying.

Comment: As I understand it, all the words ***go, goes, went***, and ***going*** are variants of the same "lexeme". But ***cats*** consists of two "morphemes", because the pluralising ***s*** contains meaning *in and of itself*.

Comment: I believe that David Crystal claimed that 'ship of the desert' was a single lexeme. And that he introduced the term. See this article at [Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=22685).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say lexemes are entries in a dictionary and morphemes are elements of word formation and grammatical endings. The theories about morphemes have become inflated in a way that one can write a book about it, but the problems of morphology don't affect normal grammar. Most things in my view are trivial hairsplitting.

Comment: I thought a Lexeme was a fancy car, and morpheme was what they gave me when I had my last kidney stone.

Comment: That was not very useful to the OP, but I must admit it is a funny joke :D

Comment: @HotLicks: Too bad they didn't give you the lexeme for that kidney stone.